# "And" Operator not working in graph explorer

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of guests whith `accountenabled eq true`:

```
/v1.0/users?&$filter=userType eq 'Guest' and AccountEnabled eq 'true'
```

I receive an error because of an `Invalid filter clause`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not caused by `and`, we need to remove the `''` with the `'true'`, just use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?&$filter=userType eq 'Guest' and AccountEnabled eq true`, then it will work fine.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From your question, parameter type is invalid. We need to pass suitable parameter values for the corresponding argument/parameter. 'true' is string but true should be bool/object.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?&$filter=userType eq 'Guest' and AccountEnabled eq true
```